# How to read data from nodes and display in this complex table?

Tags: 7

I have some nodes in my site

```
Day         Color   Type    Value
01-01-2018  blue    A       4
02-01-2018  yellow  B       3
02-01-2018  orange  C       2
03-01-2018  red     B       8
```

I need to show this data in the following way (NOT USING VIEWS):

[image]

Does anyone knows if it's possible using the table theme in Drupal?
I don't think it's possible to have the double header either.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to flatten the data yourself, as you're grouping by date (you'd have to regardless of the double header and colspans), but yes, `theme_table` can accommodate that.

I haven't tested this but it should be at least near to working. The key points to note are `colspan`, which does what you'd think, and `header`, which will mark a cell to be rendered as `<th>` rather than `<td>`. Meaning you can stuff the second row of headers into the body. Not ideal, as they'll be inside a `<tbody>`, but I suspect good enough.

```
$header = [
  [
    'data' => '',
    'colspan' => 2,
  ],
  [
    'data' => 'Type',
    'colspan' => 3,
  ],
];

$rows = [
  [
    [
      'data' => 'Day',
      'header' => TRUE,
    ],
    // Other header rows here, with 'header' => TRUE
  ]
];

// Loop through your grouped data
foreach ($data as $item) {
  $rows[] = [
    $item->date,
    $item->colours,
    $item->type_a,
    $item->type_b,
    $item->type_c,
  ];
}

$build = [
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
];
```